# does flink stream is an immutable?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I need to split a stream of data using flink.

the 1st one named "myDs" - contains duplicate data

the 2nd one named "goodDataStream" should filter duplicates

the partial code is:

```
goodDataStream = myDs
             .filter( new DedupeFilterFunction())  // does this line affects myDs also?


// createSync for goodDataStream


// createSync for myDs
```

my question is:

does it means that myDs sync also includes the new DedupeFilterFunction()

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataStream` is immutable. So in your case `myDs` will not have the `DedupeFilterFunction` applied.

Comment: does immutability also apply to Table API? Say I have a single source table backed by Kafka, and I am running two aggregation queries on the table and output to two different sinks. Will these two queries affect each other as they read from a same table? My concern is: "the table is backed by Kafka, if the record is processed by one query, then the record may not be available to the other query since the event is already processed." thanks!